# How to specify 2 or more output Labels in a TensorFlow Regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Using the TensorFlow Regression tutorial (see: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression) as a starting point, I'm wanting to extend it to consider 2 output Labels. The model should be trained to predict these 2 outputs from 5 other inputs. Training data is defined through a .csv file which is importing, defining column headings etc. all without issue.

So far I've used train_stats.pop twice to exclude the 2 'output' columns from the training set.
I've also defined 2 nodes on the final layer to hold the 2 Labels I'm wanting the model to predict:

```
def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(**2**)
  ])
```

However I'm struggling to figure out how to define the 2 output Labels. One is called "Tj", the the other is called "Tleads". The original tutorial just sets one, i.e.:

```
train_labels = train_dataset.pop('Tj')
test_labels = test_dataset.pop('Tj')
```

but I don't know how to redefine these lines to set both Labels.

Advice welcome!

Comment: Read about functional API models.

Comment: Figured it out. Needed to add 2 nodes on the final layer, construct a 2D array for the training and testing Label set and flatten the test_labels output for the error histogram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentioning the Answer in this section (even though it is mentioned in the Comments Section) for the benefit of the community.

Tensorflow Regression can be Modeled for 2 Output Labels by

1. Adding `2 nodes` on the `final layer`
2. Constructing a `2D array` for the `training and testing Label set` and
3. Flattening the `test_labels` output for the error histogram.